# Where should I place my .sql files containing records that I am using in my Database Seeders in laravel project hierarchy folder

Tags: php, laravel, orm, eloquent

I have two sql files namely Cities.sql and States.sql and I am using Database seeders to populate my data in database. Following is the code for Seeders:

### City Table

```
class CitiesTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
        DB::table('cities')->delete();
        $sql = file_get_contents('app/database/seeds/cities.sql');
        DB::statement($sql);
    }

}
```

### State Table

```
class StatesTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    //put your code here
    public function run()
    {
        DB::table('states')->delete();
        $sql = file_get_contents('app/database/seeds/states.sql');
        DB::statement($sql);
    }

}
```

Comment: In the path you usef for `file_get_contents`: `app/database/seeds` ? Also your files have names with Capital letters and you used in code file names without capital letters.

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek my file names are not with capital letters and I have changed the path from mentioned in my question to app_path('database\seeds\filename.sql');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you have is fine. All I'd say though is rather than use `file_get_contents('app/.....')` you should find a better way to refer to the directory. Because (I assume) the sql files are alongside your seeders, you *could* just use `file_get_contents(__DIR__.'/cities.sql');` etc. or alternatively use `file_get_contents(app_path('database/seeds/cities.sql'));` kinda thing.

That said, I try not to use SQL files and instead seed using code. The benefit of doing this, other than not having this dilemma, is that you can be more database-agnostic. For example, if you switch to some other DB driver in the future, one that doesn't use the exact same syntax as you have in your `.sql` files, then you will run into problems doing this. But if you use `DB::insert()` statements, you'll last a lot longer.

Comment: you are right but what is bothering me is where I should put these files , I mean currently I have these files alongside my seeders. Is this the right folder for .sql files or I should move these files to some other directory of laravel project? Kindly comment. Thank you

Comment: As I said at the top of the answer I think what you are doing is fine (i.e. alongside seeders). Definitely within `app/database/` as it's very specifically related to that, and `seeders` makes a lot of sense as they are for seeding the database. Realistically, with Laravel, there's a lot of doing what feels best for you, so if you want these supporting files in their own place, put them there, but if it feels better to keep common stuff together (seeders in seeders) as it does for me, do that.